# How to retry on error only inner observable?

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I have the following sample:

```
const result = http.get('http://google.com')

               .switchMap(() => 'http://example.com')

               // This retry should retry only example.com
               .retryWhen(error => 
                    (error instanceof Response && error.status == 429) ?
                     Observable.timeout(5000) : Observable.throw(error))

               // This retry should retry google.com
               .retryWhen(error => Observable.timeout(5000))
```

I want to have a retryWhen which will retry only his immediate parent. And then in case of a global error I will retry the whole sequence. Is there an easy way with RxJS 5 ?

UPD: These are just examples. In reality situation is more complex I just need an idea for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need put the `retryWhen` inside the `switchMap`:

```
const inner = http.get('http://example.com')
      // This retry should retry only example.com
      .retryWhen(error => 
       (error instanceof Response && error.status == 429) ?
        Observable.timer(5000) : Observable.throw(error))

const outer = http.get('http://google.com')
  .switchMap(() => inner)
  // This retry should retry google.com
  .retryWhen(error => Observable.timeout(5000))
```